# Upload base64 image to php server and save to MySql

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, ionic-framework

From my phone, I am taking a picture with ngcordova and convert it to base64. This works perfectly and can be displayed on my phone app just after it.

Now, I am trying to send the base64 string to my PHP server with the $http from angularjs, but for some reason, it does not receive it. Here is the code.

```
var request = $http({
  method: "post",
  url: mainUrl + "spus.php",
  params: {
    action: "saveLocationPicture",
    locationPicture: spuInfo.locationPicture  <-- "data:image/png;base64,/9j/44AQSk..."
  }
});
```

I said that the php server does not receive it, but I think it is not true. Why? Because if I send a shorter string (less than 835 characters), the php server receives it and I can save it to the MySql database. For test, I created 2 columns in the MySql table. One is of type LongBlob and the other one LongText. It should have plenty of room. ;-)

First of all, is there any limitation to the string that can be sent to the $http "params"?

If so, what is the limit?

Maybe it is my PHP server configuration that cannot handle the long base64 string? What do you think?

Thanks

******** UPDATE *******

Hi all,

I found a partial solution so far and wanted to share with you.

I can now send my big base64 image to my php server by doing that:

```
    var request = $http({
      method: "post",
      url: mainUrl + "spus.php",
      data: {
        action: "saveLocationPicture",
        hw_id: spuInfo.hw_id,
        locationPicture: spuInfo.locationPicture
      }
    });
```

And, in my php code:

```
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);

    $action2 = $request->action;
    $hw_id2 = $request->hw_id;
    $locationPicture = $request->locationPicture;
```

Now, the only problem that I see is this in the Chrome debug console view:

> GET data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAADFQWERTYUIOPHGJTIYKHMBFHTYF…kZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD//gAEKgD/4gIcSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIMbGNtcwIQFFFFFFFFFFF net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Does somebody know why I am having that?

Thanks

Comment: i guess your request is too larg(from php confie).chek php settings

Comment: I did not have the "post_max_size" included in my php.ini file. I read about it and the default is 8M. This should be plenty enough for the string.

Anyway, I added the field and put "12M" because it needs to be higher than "upload_max_filesize" that is already set to 10M.

Unfortunately, it did not work. :-(

Any other suggestions?

Comment: first of all check databse.insert your image in table in base64 code and try read it by php

Comment: I looked into the error from the web server (I am using BOA) and found this:

10.74.17.134 - - [14/Jan/2015:18:06:58 +0000] request "(null)" ("(null)"): Header too long at 1028 bytes: "POST /cgi-bin/php/spus.php?action=saveLocationPict...

I also noticed all the forward slash became "%2F" from my base64 string. I don't think it is the issue though.

I said to myself that maybe it is a configuration in my web server that is not correct.

One field is called "SinglePostLimit: The maximum allowable number of bytes in a single POST.". This one is already set to 10MB.

Other suggestions?

Comment: I moved the answer you gave to the answers section. Please keep questions and answers separate - it helps people in the future find the information faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try the [Cordova File Transfer Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/doc/index.md) to upload your image file to the server, retrieve the file using $_FILE , covert it into blob object and store it.

Comment: yeah, just discovered that this weekend. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found why I got that error! The base64 image that I was using was just random character and this cause the issue.